# Drupal 6.20, fields missing when viewing a node appear when editing

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a node that contains 6 fields. When the user **views** the node, the only fields that appear are those for which the user has already entered data. When the user **edits** the node, all the fields are visible. I have inspected the HTML to confirm that the missing fields are not being hidden by CSS. How do I make all the fields visible when the user **views** the node?

Comment: What would you like to display for empty fields ?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is empty, then drupal won't display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a views with Views Module http://drupal.org/project/views  and display all fields with a default value.

Contemplate is also a good solution to create easily template for your node : http://drupal.org/project/contemplate